# How to Async send and receive websocket messages with python

Tags: python, websocket, python-asyncio

How do you send and receive messages using pythons asyncio and the websockets library?
I am using Django Channels as the socket server. So basically I am trying to send and receive from this socket server.

I can easily send messages to my websocket server using:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

async def main():
    uri = f"{wsPrefix}stream/{machineSerial}/?{token}"
    async with websockets.connect(uri, ping_interval = None) as websocket:
        try:
            cap = acapture.open(0)
        except:
            asyncio.sleep(1)
            cap = acapture.open(0)
        while True:
            check,frame = cap.read()
            if not websocket.open:
                print("### reconnecting ###")
                await websockets.connect(uri,ping_interval = None)
            if check:
                frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
                check, jpeg = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
                frame = jpeg.tobytes()
                frame = bytearray(frame)
                await websocket.send(frame)
            await asyncio.sleep(0.05)
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import websockets
    import asyncio
    import acapture
    import cv2
    from deviceSpecificVals import machineSerial, token
    import deviceSpecificVals.url

    urlPrefix = deviceSpecificVals.url
    wsPrefix = deviceSpecificVals.wsPrefix

    asyncio.run(main())
```

But how can you add another async function here to always be listening for a message? I want the receiver to finish the script and close when it receives a 'close' message.

I tried:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

async def connect():
    uri = f"{wsPrefix}stream/{machineSerial}/?{token}"
    async with websockets.connect(uri, ping_interval = None) as websocket:
        return websocket
        
        
async def rcv(websocket):
    while True:
        msg = await websocket.recv()
        print(f"< {msg}")
    
async def send(websocket):
    uri = f"{wsPrefix}stream/{machineSerial}/?{token}"
    try:
        cap = acapture.open(0)
    except:
        asyncio.sleep(1)
        cap = acapture.open(0)
    while True:
        check,frame = cap.read()
        if not websocket.open:
            print("### reconnecting ###")
            await websockets.connect(uri,ping_interval = None)
        if check:
            frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            check, jpeg = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
            frame = jpeg.tobytes()
            frame = bytearray(frame)
            await websocket.send(frame)
        await asyncio.sleep(0.05)

async def main():
        websocket = await connect()
        asyncio.ensure_future(send(websocket))
        asyncio.ensure_future(rcv(websocket))
        await asyncio.sleep(100000)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import websockets
    import asyncio
    import acapture
    import cv2
    from deviceSpecificVals import machineSerial, token
    import deviceSpecificVals.url

    urlPrefix = deviceSpecificVals.url
    wsPrefix = deviceSpecificVals.wsPrefix

    asyncio.run(main())
```

This will not connect to websocket, it is almost as if the connect function is not returning the websocket object. I am also very new to async, and trying to understand what is happening here

Answer (score 0):

Websocket is a protocol, so you have to run a web engine that supports that protocol.  I like `gevent` better since you can run both the webserver and the websocket on the same server and it will upgrade the connection for you if it sees it.

Here is a template for you to get started.  Obviously you need to connect this to a websocket client.

Instead of AsyncIO I use `gevent` since the monkey patching makes the async process seamless.

```
from gevent import monkey, signal_handler as sig, sleep
monkey.patch_all()
from gevent.pywsgi import WSGIServer
from geventwebsocket.handler import WebSocketHandler
import signal
import traceback
import ujson as json
import bottle
from bottle import route, get, post, request, response


@route('/ws')
def handle_websocket():
    ws = request.environ.get('wsgi.websocket')
    if not ws:
        abort(400, 'Expected WebSocket request.')
    while 1:
        message = None
        try:
            with Timeout(2, False) as timeout: # this adds a timeout to the wait for recieve, since it will wait forever.  
                message = ws.receive()
            if message:
                message = json.loads(message)
        except WebSocketError:
            break
        except Exception as exc:
            traceback.print_exc()
            sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Server Running...')
    botapp = bottle.app()
    server = WSGIServer(("0.0.0.0", 80), botapp, handler_class=WebSocketHandler)

    def shutdown():
        print('Shutting down ...')
        server.stop(timeout=60)
        exit(signal.SIGTERM)

    sig(signal.SIGTERM, shutdown)
    sig(signal.SIGINT, shutdown)
    server.serve_forever()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will update my question to be more clear. I apologize for not stating this, but I am using Django Channels, and I am trying to communicate with it using this python script

Comment: It doesn't matter, you would end up using something like Daphne anyway to create a websocket connection, this would just replace that solution.

Answer (score 0):

I know I am late to the conversation but this is something I am working on myself.  In my case, I am streaming data to the server and the server will respond sporadically back to me.  So as I transition from ws4py to websockets in python, I am presented with the same challenge.  I haven't written out the code but if you use this sample code as a template and extrapolate from it, you will have what you are asking.  I can respond to a more specific solution once I am done.

The idea is to put your recv and send in a task, and in a while loop only schedule another task if the previous task is not finished.

```
import asyncio
import random

async def send(tag):
    print(">", tag)
    await asyncio.sleep(random.uniform(0.5, 5))
    print("<", tag)
    return tag

async def recv(tag):
    print(">>", tag)
    await asyncio.sleep(random.uniform(5, 10))
    print("<<", tag)
    return tag

async def main_loop():
    task = asyncio.create_task(send(1), name='send_amro')
    task2 = asyncio.create_task(recv(99), name='recv_amro')
    tasks = [task, task2]
    done, pending = await asyncio.wait(tasks, return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)

    print("done: ", done)
    print("pending: ", pending)

    list_tasks = list(pending)
    print("pending coro:", list_tasks[0].get_coro())
    print("pening name:", list_tasks[0].get_name())

    if list_tasks[0].get_name() == 'recv_amro':
        print("Skipping scheduling a Receive task, its not yet finished")
        tasks = [pending.pop()]
    else:
        task3 = asyncio.create_task(recv(100), name='recv_amro_2')
        tasks = [pending.pop(), task3]

    done, pending = await asyncio.wait(tasks)


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main_loop())
```

So the goal of this is to mimic my use case where I upload data frequently but receive data sporadically.

So I schedule a send and a recv task, but get control the moment one of them finishes.  Do something in between and only schedule a new task for the one that finished.  The way I plan to do this is to filter the pending tasks by the name I assigned them and skip schedule another one.

Here is an example of how to implement a send/receive websocket solution where the communication between the client and the server is not symmetrical.  In your case you can modify the code below to break from the loop if you want close the connection since you plan to kill the websocket as soon as you receive a message.

```
import asyncio
import websockets


#Use this for debugging
SEND_TASK_NAME = "send_function"
RECV_TASK_NAME = "recv_function"
MAX_FAILURES = 3
WS_URL = "YOUR WEBSOCKET URL"


async def send_data(websocket, data) -> bool:
    try:
        await websocket.send(data)
        return True
    except websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosed as connection_closed:
        # Do closed connection handling
        return False
    except Exception as e:
        # Do generic error handling
        return False


async def send_task_func(websocket) -> bool:
    block = "SOME DATA TO SEND, COULD BE BINARY, JSON, ..., could be read/retrieved from somewhere else"
    if block:
        res = await send_data(websocket, block)
        if res:
            # Do some handling if needed
            pass
        else:
            # Do some handling if needed
            pass

    else:
        # Handle error case where you were unable to have data to send if applicable
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        return False  # May not be an error case

    return True


async def recv_task_func(websocket) -> None:
    m = await websocket.recv()
    # Do something with the message, if receiving requires error handling then monitor the result in the loop
    return


async def send_and_receive_loop():
    async with websockets.connect(WS_URL, ping_timeout=None, close_timeout=1) as websocket:
        try:
            send_task = asyncio.create_task(send_task_func(websocket), name=SEND_TASK_NAME)
            recv_task = asyncio.create_task(recv_task_func(websocket), name=RECV_TASK_NAME)
            tasks = [send_task, recv_task]
            done_tasks, pending_tasks = await asyncio.wait(tasks, return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)

            failed_to_send_data = 0
            while True:
                tasks = []
                for done_task in done_tasks:
                    if done_task.get_name() == SEND_TASK_NAME:
                        if done_task.result is False:
                            failed_to_send_data += 1
                        else:
                            failed_to_send_data = 0

                        send_task = asyncio.create_task(send_task_func(websocket), name=SEND_TASK_NAME)
                        tasks.append(send_task)
                    elif done_task.get_name() == RECV_TASK_NAME:
                        recv_task = asyncio.create_task(recv_task_func(websocket), name=RECV_TASK_NAME)
                        tasks.append(recv_task)

                for pending_task in pending_tasks:
                    tasks.append(pending_task)

                if failed_to_send_data > MAX_FAILURES:
                    print("Aborting websocket")
                    break

                if len(tasks) > 0:
                    done_tasks, pending_tasks = await asyncio.wait(tasks, return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)
                else:
                    print("No tasks are going to be scheduled")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Exception while sending/receiving data through WS {e}.  Terminating WS connection")


        # If we are here, we need to cancel any pending tasks before the websocket gets closed
        for pending_task in pending_tasks:
            try:
                print(f"Cancelling pending tasks as we exited loop: {pending_task.get_name()}")
                pending_task.cancel()
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Exception cancelling task: {e}")

        print("StreamClientNew::main_loop: Closing Websocket")
        await websocket.close()
        print("Done closing websocket")
        print("All done, exiting function")
        return

loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
loop.run_until_complete(send_and_receive_loop())
loop.close()
```